# Need help in passing the results of a function into a parameter for a new instance in qnaMaker

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am labbing out a Custom Question Answering bot to query my Azure Language Service for internal QnA. I am using one of the [BotBuilder Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/12.customQABot) and have updated the sample utilizing a User-Assigned Managed Identity to retrieve 2 secrets from an Azure KeyVault and pass the string values into the CustomQuestionAnswering instance. This is part of enhancing security for the bot.

This block of code runs the main() function which is working fine and the console successfully displays the endpointKey and host values pulled from KeyVault. But it's not passing the values into the "CustomQuestionAnswering" instance. When I run the bot, it gives the error **[onTurnError] unhandled error: ReferenceError: endpointKey is not defined** when using the Bot Framework Emulator to query the language service.

```
(async () => {
            try {
                var results = await main();
                const { retrievedKey, retrievedEndpoint } = results;
                const endpointKey = retrievedKey;
                const host = retrievedEndpoint;
                console.log(endpointKey, host);
                
                this.qnaMaker = new CustomQuestionAnswering(
                    {
                    knowledgeBaseId: process.env.ProjectName,
                    endpointKey: endpointKey,
                    host: host
                });            
            } catch (err) {
                console.warn(`QnAMaker Exception: ${ err } Check your Custom QnA configuration in .env`);
            }
        })();
```

This is the main() function.

```
async function main() {
            const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential({
                managedIdentityClientId: process.env["MANAGED_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID"],
            });
        
            const keyVaultName = process.env["KEY_VAULT_NAME"];
            const url = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
        
            const kvClient = new SecretClient(url, credential);
        
            // Set these variables to the names you created for your secrets
            const keySecretName = process.env["KEY_SECRET_NAME"];
            const endpointSecretName = process.env["ENDPOINT_SECRET_NAME"];
        
            //console.log("Retrieving secrets from ", keyVaultName);
            var retrievedKey =  (await kvClient.getSecret(keySecretName)).value;
            var retrievedEndpoint =  (await kvClient.getSecret(endpointSecretName)).value;
            //console.log("Your secret key value is: ", retrievedKey);
            //console.log("Your secret endpoint value is: ", retrievedEndpoint);

            return{ retrievedKey, retrievedEndpoint};
        }
```

What can I do to ensure the values from main get passed into the this.qnaMaker properties?